# Hashing Questions

Tags: math, hash, cryptography

I've been doing some questions related to hashing and came across these three. I am a bit confused as how to go about solving them.

**The question is stated as follows,**

Suppose a hashing function H(*m*) that takes any input *m* and produces a fixed-length 64-bit digest *h*. Answer the following questions

a) How many hashes would you need to compute in order to have a 50% probability of finding any two inputs *m1* and *m2* such that H(*m1*) = H(*m2*)?

b) Given some hash digest h, how many inputs would you need to hash in order to have a 50% probability of finding an input *m* such that h = H(*m*)?

c) Given some input *m1*, how many inputs would you need to hash in order to have a 50% probability of finding an input *m2* such that H(*m1*) = H(*m2*)

**Would we simply be using the birthday paradox to solve these questions or is there another way to solve them?**

Comment: a) is effectively answered by the birthday problem or paradox, b) is the pre-image problem, and c) is the 2nd pre-image problem. These properties are discussed in the [cryptographic hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) wikipedia article.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk : If your comment answered this question, you should post it as an answer, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.